# bpy add object in game

Tags: scripting, game-engine

is it possible to add an object inside the game engine with upbge 3.X.X while having game physics work properly ?
What I'm doing is:

```
patch = bpy.data.objects['Patch1']

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        if i or j:
            copy = patch.copy()
            copy.data = patch.data.copy()
            bpy.context.collection.objects.link(copy)
            copy.location = (i*256, j*256, 0)
```

This is connected to an 'always' sensor set on tap and does add my patches of ground as expected, but there are no physics and the player goes through the objects.
I tried adding

> copy.game.physics_type = 'STATIC'

But this doesn't sort my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use `own.scene.convertBlenderObject(bpy_object)` to wrap it in a `KX_Object` / convert its logic

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This is what I found out eventually. There is also the call reinstancePhysicsMesh() that can come in handy if modifying the geometry in game.